# Pass parameters in Html.BeginForm that don't come from <input>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-post, html.beginform

I am using `Html.BeginForm("Details", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post)` to send some parameters to my `Controller`. Everything is working fine. However, it only works for `<input>` tags within the Html. Is there a way to post the value of other tags? for example a `<span>` or anything else? so at the end in my `ActionResult Details()`, I could receive those values within the `<span>`?

Thank you

Comment: The problem you're facing is that the `BeginForm()` method is used to write a `<form>` tag, which posts data to the server from `<input>` tags.  I'm not sure what your experience with HTML forms is, but this is a decent primer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware of this.

Comment: Welcome to web development.  That site altogether is very helpful for learning the ins and outs of HTML, javascript, and CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't. Only `input`, `select` and `textarea` controls values are posted to server. You can set in background a hidden input control with span value but you can't expect span to be automatically posted.

Comment: This isn't technically correct since you can use other html elements in a form other than input controls. For instance, a textarea or select would be be valid form elements and their value/selected values can be sent using a form submission.

Comment: @heymega: by input controls I meant to say controls allowing user input, not elements of type `input`. I could clarify if this is not clear enough

Comment: @ClaudioRedi, Technically a <div contentEditable="true">` allows user input but wont post back :)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke: clarified my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you use javascript, you can. example below.

```
document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var form = document.getElementById('myForm');

    var data = new FormData();
    // put whatever you want to put through data.append([name], [value])

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", form.action);
    xhr.send(data); 
};
```